# AngularJS - Chosen ng-model is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get value when I select an option from an AngularJS chosen localytics dropdown.
Here's the code for the dropdown:

```
<select chosen style="width: 250px"
        ng-model="StudentId"
        ng-options="allStudent.StudentId as allStudent.Name for allStudent in allStudent">
        <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<h2>Chosen with static options: {{ StudentId }}</h2>
<input type="button" value="Search" ng-click="GetStdCourseList(StudentId)">
```

And in my controller I have the following function:

```
    $scope.GetStdCourseList = function (StudentId) {
        alert(StudentId);
    };
```

When I use alert then it show me 'Undefined' instead of showing value
How can I solve this?

Actually this is ok and I get value when I'm not using chosen search but when I use 'chosen' then it's not working.... Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since your model is StudentId you can ignore the param in your function and simple use $scope.StudentId

Comment: What is `chosen` attribute about?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not selected any options before clicking the button. This works fine for me when I select the option.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.allStudent = [{StudentId: 0, Name: 'name1'}, {StudentId: 1, Name: 'name2'}];
     $scope.GetStdCourseList = function (StudentId) {
        alert(StudentId);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select chosen style="width: 250px"
          ng-model="StudentId"
          ng-options="allStudent.StudentId as allStudent.Name for allStudent in allStudent">
          <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>

  <h2>Chosen with static options: {{ StudentId }}</h2>
  <input type="button" value="Search" ng-click="GetStdCourseList(StudentId)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Nitheesh.But I think 'chosen' that is used in your code is not working. Please check the screenshot of my post..

Comment: @SubhoGhose what is this chosen attribute for?

Answer (score 0):

well, since ng-model's object is $scope.something itself, try to

replace

```
alert(StudentId)
```

become

```
alert($scope.StudentId)
```

and i don't think on this case you will need param. just ignore it because $scope covered it for you

that's will do

edited for better readability